# Пагинация в php из БД (асинхронная)

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, пагинация

Нужно вывести по 3 записи на страницу, без перезагрузки страницы. Вроде просто, пишу:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','Blog');
$query = 'select * from Notes limit 0, 3';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

, заменить числа на переменные и будет счастье. Но при замене выдает ошибку в последней строке "mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result".
Уже часов 5 ломаю голову над этой пагинацией, может посоветуете что ?
Переменные оборачивал в {}, и двойные фигурные пробовал,и кавычки одинарные-двойные. Беда из-за плохого знания методов на мой взгляд, но сроки жмут, а нужные мысли и статьи все не приходят =(

Answer (score 0):

Скорее проблема не в числах, а в отсутствии данных на следующих страницах, из-за чего `$result == false`
То есть нужно обернуть результат

```
if ($result) {
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

У меня в проекте такие пагинаторы

```
public function getForPage($table, $page, $perPage = 10)
{
    $from = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
    $table = $this->wrapColumn($table);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table .
        " ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . (int) $from . ', ' . (int) $perPage;
    return $this->db->query($sql) ?: [];
}

private function wrapColumn($column)
{
    return '`' . $this->db->real_escape_string($column) . '`';
}
```

По HTML это так выглядит (Bootstrap):

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php if ($page == 1) { ?>
        <li class="disabled"><span>Назад</span></li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="<?=url($url, ['page' => $page - 1]);?>" rel="prev">Предыдущая</a></li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if (isset($hasNextPage) && $hasNextPage) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?=url($url, ['page' => $page + 1]);?>" rel="next">Следующая</a></li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="disabled"><span>Следующая</span></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Данные есть и они выводятся. Скорее всего при отсутствии данных, ошибку выдало бы.

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев как сейчас числа подставляются?

Comment: с числами все работает, при замене их на переменные выдает ошибку указанную в вопросе (выше)

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев `var_dump($query);` каждый раз делайте, чтобы понять, почему запрос результат не возвращает

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев зачем использовать `mysqli_fetch_all`, когда mysqli_result implements Traversable ?

Comment: откуда Вы данные для $page берете ? по mysqli_fetch_all, второй метод я не знаю, но Вы ведь сами используете первый ?!

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев `$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;`

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев mysqli_result это объект, возвращаемый функцией mysqli_query. То есть у нас это `$result`. Суть в том, что его можно как массив через foreach перебирать.